# Find the contour in a radiograph

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I just started learning openCV and I want to write a program that can detect the organs in a radiograph. The result I want to have look like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkVlh.png).
I tried cv2.findContours but it can't detect the correct one, then I use convex hull and it return [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEFVM.jpg) which is not the one I want neither.
Is there a other way that you can find the contours in openCV that can help me with this one? I can only find two ways above.

Answer (score 1):

you must use the validContours so you can use this code after use findContours and you change the boundRect value to find the area that you want

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contourss.size());
                vector<Rect> boundRect(contourss.size());
                vector<Point2f>center(contourss.size());
                vector<float>radius(contourss.size());
                //Get poly contours
                for (int i = 0; i < contourss.size(); i++)
                {
                    approxPolyDP(Mat(contourss[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
                }
                //Get only important contours, merge contours that are within another
                vector<vector<Point> > validContours;
                for (int i = 0; i < contours_poly.size(); i++){
                    Rect r = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
                    if (r.area() < 200)continue;
                    bool inside = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < contours_poly.size(); j++){
                        if (j == i)continue;
                        Rect r2 = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[j]));
                        if (r2.area() < 200 || r2.area()<r.area())continue;
                        if (r.x>r2.x&&r.x + r.width<r2.x + r2.width&&
                            r.y>r2.y&&r.y + r.height < r2.y + r2.height){
                            inside = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (inside)continue;
                    validContours.push_back(contours_poly[i]);
                }
                //Get bounding rects
                for (int i = 0; i < validContours.size(); i++){
                    boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(validContours[i]));
                }
```

Comment: Thank you with your code I can find the exact contours I want

Comment: you can change the value of area and boundRect to find your area contours